# Validation rules not working when embedding FOSRegistrationFormType

Tags: php, fosuserbundle, symfony-2.1, symfony-sonata

Hi I want to embed part of registration form from FOSUserBundle into another one. When I tried to add existing email, "Integrity constraint violation" exception was raised because unique validator is not used. How can I fix this. When registration form is used separately, validators are working correctly.

Main form:

```
class SoldierType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ...
            ->add('user', new NameFormType('Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User')) 

        ;

    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'validation_groups' => array('registration')
        ));

    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'wnc_soldierbundle_soldiertype';
    }
}
```

NameForm

```
namespace Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;
use FOS\UserBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType as BaseForm;

class NameFormType extends BaseForm
{

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('firstname')
                ->add('lastname')
                ->add('email', 'email', array('label' => 'form.email', 'translation_domain' => 'FOSUserBundle'));

    }


    public function getName()
    {
        return 'fos_user_name';
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding `cascade_validation` will make validation working in embedded forms.

```
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'validation_groups' => array('Registration'),
            'cascade_validation' => true,
        ));


    }
```